# How to recognize the shape of traffic sign?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, shapes, image-recognition

I'm trying to recognize the traffic signs.The shape information is a very important information.I'd like to combine color and shape information to make a rough classification of traffic signs.The question is that how can I determine the shape(triangle,circle,eight-side form,etc) of traffic signs? Can anyone give some advice?(I know there exists Ramer-douglas-peucker Algorithm which can handle the problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed with the following steps:

1. Find a way to crop your sign with as little background as possible
2. Apply a threshold to convert the sign into a simple shape
3. Create a [topological skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) and apply your algorihm, or a variation of it to classify the skeleton.

Comment: Thank you! I've solve this problem by using contour approximation algorithm and by counting the number of vertices to recognize the shape